# Reload nginx configuration when rsync updates nginx.conf

Tags: debian, rsync, nginx, crontab

I have two web servers, server1 and server2.

On server2 there is an rsync command, scheduled in crontab, that updates /etc/nginx folder when I make some changes on server1:

`*/5 * * * * rsync -avzhe ssh user@server1:/etc/nginx/ /etc/nginx/`

How can I know that rsync has changed something so that I have to reload nginx?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Adding option -i and removing -v, rsync outputs something only if files were changed. So I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

RSYNC=$(rsync -aizhe ssh user@server1:/etc/nginx/ /etc/nginx/)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        if [ -n "${RSYNC}" ]; then
                /usr/sbin/nginx -s reload
                echo "reloaded."
        fi
else
        exit 1
fi
```

and put it in crontab.